# jquery modal dialog loads xhtml page but not closing

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I have a modal dialog that opens when a button is clicked, and when opened it loads a `.xhtml` page .

Inside this XHTML page, I have a button for passing some data back to the parent window (where the dialog is initialized), and after that I want to close the dialog but it won’t close!! This is my code:

First page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                         
    var selected_row_data_json;

    window.lang = new jquery_lang_js();

    $().ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup ({
            // Disable caching of AJAX responses
            cache: false
        });
        createDataListDialog();                
    });     

    function setSelectedRowJsonData(row_data_)
    {  
       selected_row_data_json = row_data_;                           
    }           

    function setFormSelectedValues()
    {
        $('#dataListDialog').dialog('close');  
    }

    function createDataListDialog()
    {
        $("#dataListDialog").dialog(
        {                   
            autoOpen: false,                      
            modal: true,                    
            resizable: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {   
            /* <![CDATA[ */                    
                $('#dataListDialog').css('overflow', 'hidden');

                $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
                $(this).load("data_list.xhtml");                       
            /* ]]> */
            },
            height: 400,
            width: 550,
            close: function (event, ui) {                        
                $(this).dialog('destroy');
                createDataListDialog();                        
            },
            create: function(event, ui)   
            {                                                  
                $(this).parents(".ui-dialog").css("padding", 0);                           
                $(this).parents(".ui-dialog:first")
                    .find(".ui-dialog-content").css("padding", 0);
            }
        });       
    }
</script>

<f:view>
    <h:outputLabel value="Code:"  lang="en" onclick="openDialog('dataListDialog');return false;" />

    <div id="dataListDialog" lang="en" title="Users" dir="#{user.dir}">                
    </div>
</f:view>
```

`data_list.xhtml` page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test()
    {
        window.parent.setSelectedRowJsonData(selected_row_data_json);
        window.parent.setFormSelectedValues();
    }
</script> 

<h:form id="dataListForm" ">   
    <input type="button" onclick="test()" value="TEST">/input>
</h:form>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Missing something? Why isn’t the dialog being closed from the loaded page?

**UPDATE**:
If the loaded page is an `html` page then it works good - the dialog is closing. the problem is when the page is `xhtml` page.. how can I fix this?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you're calling `createDataListDialog()` in the close event. It looks like it recreates the dialog every time it closes.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way of doing this would be firing off the `test()` function after the load completes successfully -- that is, bind it to the `complete` event:

```
$(this).load("data_list.xhtml",
    complete: function(response, status, xhr) {
        window.parent.setSelectedRowJsonData(selected_row_data_json);
        window.parent.setFormSelectedValues();
    });
```

Bonus: add some conditionals that handle server errors using the `status` object.